# Oracle PL/SQL datetime math - intervals

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, oracle10g, date-arithmetic

I've been using syntax like `{?EndDate} - INTERVAL '1' YEAR` for a while now, and I knew there was an issue that I was going to hit eventually, and I just hit it. I tried to do `DATE '2010-12-31' - INTERVAL '6' MONTH`, and it choked because there's no June 31st. What's the most efficient and consistent way to code this? While tracking down the person who made the decision to do it this way would be more satisfying, it's impractical. :-)

Comment: Have they never heard of February?

Comment: Like most decisions of this nature, it was made by a committee and it is part of ANSI SQL (92 or 99, I'm not sure).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a *constistent* way, since it certainly depends on what someone thinks is 6 months. Yet, imho, it is safe to assume that `add_months` is a standard way (at least in Oracle) to subtract or add months:

```
select add_months(DATE '2010-12-31',-6)  from dual;
```

This expression returns June 30th 2010 (which is the last day in that month (as is the 31st in december).

Comment: Worth noting that select add_months(date '2011-02-28',1) from dual will return March 31st, not March 28th.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification there, Gary -- if it's an issue, I'll figure out some other way to do it.